# Ionic serve taking too much time like 4 to 6 minutes while compiling ionic 3 project

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using ionic-3 and when I am compiling ionic project through **ionic serve** command, Its taking 4-6 mins for me.

Versions of following components:

- @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
- ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.4
Cordova Platforms  : android 7.1.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.7.1
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
Node              : v7.10.1
npm               : 5.4.2 
OS                : Linux 4.4
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : /home/spaneos/Android/Sdk
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

- node version: 7.10.0
- npm version: 5.4.2

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your system specification. If you have a higher config machine then it will take less time. I hope you got the point.

Comment: This is true, but in my case I'm sure there is some issue going on because my PC is Linux Ubuntu x64,  i7 2.6GHz, 16GB RAM DDR4, a lot of free space in HD, only a little fraction of these resources being used and yet the CLI is slow.  Any help? Thks - Of course Ionic 5 now.

Comment: Yup there is an issue regarding node version. If you update your node version then the problem might be resolved.

Comment: Updated to Node v14.10.1 (the latest at the time of writing) and it indeed solved the issue. It is taking like 10-15sec. Thanks